# 502 Bad gateway error exact after 30 seconds

Tags: php, linux, apache

On my page, there is a script which takes a long time to execute fully. While in process, after 30 seconds, I'm getting 502 Bad gateway error. I have searched for this and it seems to be the KeepAlive feature of Apache. I've tried few things to keep it alive, such as:

```
set_time_limit(-1);
header("Connection: Keep-Alive");
header("Keep-Alive: timeout=600, max=100");   
ini_set('max_execution_time', 30000);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

I have also called an Ajax function that hits a page on server in every 5 seconds. But nothing worked for me.

I'm using PHP + MySql + Apache on Linux server.

Comment: Are you working on your localhost?

Comment: No, the same code working well on my localhost. I'm facing this issue on server.

Comment: These are either PHP directives or HTTP response headers, they won't affect Apache behaviour. You need to check documentation for your exact SAPI (server API): mod_php, php-fpm...

Answer (score 3):

If you are using some type of hosting it is quite possible that between your client and your server there is a proxy or a load balancer with connection time limit set to 30 seconds. It's quite a common solution.

Try to investigate logs to find which service returns 502.